# Downloading Image from SharePoint when you have absolute url

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, dynamics-crm

```
            var webClient = new WebClient();
            string imageUrl = retriveResponse.AbsoluteUrl.ToString() + "/test.jpg";
            var webclient = new WebClient();
            webclient.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1)");
            //webclient.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Accept, "application/octet-stream");
            //webclient.Headers.Add("binaryStringRequestBody", "true");
            webclient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Username"], 
            WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Password"]);
            imageBytes = webclient.DownloadData(imageUrl);
            webclient.Dispose();
```

Comment: I am using above code but on conversion of ByteArray to Image gives broken Image. I think I am doing something wrong while retrieving the image.

Comment: `string downloadUrl = _siteURl + "/_layouts/download.aspx?SourceUrl=" + _path;`

Just construct this path for each file and then open it in a new window and the file will be downloaded automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the following commands:

Ensure you are using SharePoint Online SDK (Microsoft.SharePointOnline.CSOM).

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;
using System.Security; 

namespace DownloadSPOImage
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            const string username = "<username>@<tenant>.onmicrosoft.com";
            const string password = "<password>";
            const string url = "https://<tenant>.sharepoint.com/<site>";
            string filename = "<name>.jpg";
            string imageUrl = url+"/<library>/"+filename; 
            string destinationLocalFolder = "C:\\temp\\images";
            string destinationLocal = destinationLocalFolder + "\\" + filename;
            var securedPassword = new SecureString();
            foreach (var c in password.ToCharArray()) securedPassword.AppendChar(c);
            var credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(username, securedPassword);
            var client = new WebClient();
            client.Headers.Add("X-FORMS_BASED_AUTH_ACCEPTED", "f");
            client.Headers.Add("User-Agent: Other");
            client.Credentials = credentials;
            client.DownloadFile(imageUrl, destinationLocal);
            Console.WriteLine("Successfully Downloaded File \"{0}\" from \"{1}\"", filename, imageUrl);
            Console.WriteLine("\nDownloaded file saved in the following file system folder:\n\t" + destinationLocalFolder);
        }
    }
}
```